# How to create a custom, clickable text view layout for ListViews?

Tags: android, listview

I'm wondering how to create a custom TextView which behaves identically to the simple_list_item_1 does? From there I can tweak it to how I want. I have created a custom layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#3104B4"
        android:id="@+id/customListViewField"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the my onClickListener doesn't receive any events. I thought marking it as clickable would do the job. What else must I do?

P.S. Is there anywhere I can view the source code for android.R folders so I can see some of the implementations (such as simple_list_item_1) for myself?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering how to create a custom TextView which behaves
>   identically to the simple_list_item_1 does?

`simple_list_item_1` is responds to the ListView's `onItemClick()` from Adapter's `OnItemClickListener` so its not a individual TextView's `onClick`.

> But the my onClickListener doesn't receive any events. I thought
>   marking it as clickable would do the job. What else must I do?

Its depends on your code implementations, just wrap your custom listview row layout to adapter and implement `onItemClickListener` to ListView.

Like,

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
    // To do with List Item Click
  }
});
```